# Set readonly input fields which are empty on page load to have a specific value using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to check if all read only input fields on a page are empty on page load, and if so adjust their value so that they specify "No data avialable"

Here is the code I tried, but nothing happens, and no errors appear in the console.

```
$(function() {
  if ($('input').is('[readonly]')) {
  if ($.trim($(this).val()).length == 0)$(this).val('No data available');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('input[readonly]').val(function(index, value) {
        return value.trim() || 'No data available';
    });
});
```

Comment: @Gideon - The biggest thing wrong with yours is that you reference `this`, but it doesn't refer to the input element. You could have used `$('input[readonly]').each(function() { ... });` and then referenced `this` inside there, but what I show is shorter.